# How to create complex model on Sqflite on Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have a complex model and could not able to save them on locally wiht Sqflite (Flutter).

I am able to save the base model on db. But I could not save others.

I try to do it like this.(Video has multiple data)

```
    int res = await dbClient.insert("$tableName", game.toMap());
        for (var i = 0; i < object.videos.length; i++) {
          Video expectedList = Video.map(object.videos[i]);
          int res2 = await dbClient.insert("video", expectedList.toMap());
    }
```

This is the base model;

```
   int versionParent;
     double popularity;
     String key;
     String versionTitle;
     dynamic keywords = List<Keyword>();
     dynamic videos = List<Video>();
     dynamic genres = List<Genres>();
```

This is the map function on model;

```
 var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
     map['genres'] = genres;
     map['id'] = id;
     map['keywords'] = keywords;
     map['key'] = key;
     map['versionTitle'] = versionTitle;
     map['popularity'] = popularity;
     map['videos'] = videos;
     return map;
   }
```

this is one of the dynamic list file model;

```
    int _id;
      int _game;
      String _name;
      String _videoId;
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        var map = Map<dynamic, dynamic>();
        map['id'] = id;
        map['game'] = game;
        map['name'] = name;
        map['video_id'] = videoId;
        return map;
      }
```

this is the tables I created (I create table for all of the dynamic lists)

```
    await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $tableName(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,hypes INTEGER, updatedAt INTEGER, pulseCount INTEGER, coverCoverId INTEGER, versionParent INTEGER, popularity INTEGER, firstReleaseDate INTEGER, key TEXT , url TEXT, name TEXT, slug TEXT, summary TEXT, imageCoverId TEXT, versionTitle TEXT)');
        await db.execute(
            'CREATE TABLE video(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, game INTEGER, name TEXT, videoId TEXT)');
```

Comment: for a start map['video_id'] should be map['videoId']. Or change the field in the database table

Comment: thank you for that. I changed it. @KiroConeski

Comment: So, did you fix the problem or it is still there?

Comment: No, its still there. I have to bind those tables somehow

Comment: I fixed the problem. If anyone need help please reach me.